# Running a single powershell command with a pipe

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run

```
powershell.exe -command "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn; Get-MailboxExportRequest -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxExportRequest"
```

but for some reason, the command hangs (presumably the pipe is being interpreted differently). Is there any way to run this as a pipe rather than a logical OR?

Comment: What happens when you try that just in a PowerShell session? Will assume the issue is with the `Add-PSSnapin`

Answer (score 0):

The `-command` parameter uses a scriptblock, eiter define it in a string like this:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn; Get-MailboxExportRequest -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxExportRequest}"
```

Or just use a scriptblock in the first place:

```
powershell.exe -command {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn; Get-MailboxExportRequest -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxExportRequest }
```

The best way though would be putting it in a script file and using the -file parameter. In case you are using this for a scheduled task (just a guess) i suggest you do the latter.

Comment: This isnt really true. From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847736.aspx): _Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless the NoExit parameter is specified._. You should be able to put a scriptblock in there.